# C Win32 console ReadConsoleInput() mingw - Unexpected results from mousewheel input

Tags: c, windows

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str

> MOUSE_WHEELED 0x0004  The vertical mouse wheel was moved.

If the high word of the `dwButtonState` member contains a positive value, the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user. Otherwise, the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void);

int main()
{
    INPUT_RECORD ir[128];
    HANDLE       hStdInput  = NULL;
    HANDLE       hStdOutput = NULL;
    DWORD        nRead;
    COORD        xy;
    
    DWORD fdwSaveOldMode;
    int i;

    hStdInput=GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdOutput=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    GetConsoleMode(hStdInput, &fdwSaveOldMode);

    
    SetConsoleMode(hStdInput,ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT|ENABLE_LINE_INPUT|ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT|ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdInput);

    ReadConsoleInput(hStdInput,ir,128,&nRead);
    
    for(i=0;i<nRead;i++)
    {
        if(ir[i].EventType == MOUSE_EVENT)
        {
            if(ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags == MOUSE_WHEELED)
            {
                printf("HIWORD(dwButtonState): %d\n", HIWORD(ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState));
            }
        }               
    }   
}
```

I'm using the mingw compiler. According to Microsoft documentation I should be getting a non-positive value whenever I rotate the mouse wheel backward. That's not what is happening.

I get consistent values but they are both positive. The value for `dwButtonState` is defined as a DWORD.

When I run the above & rotate the mouse wheel forward I get the following response:

> HIWORD(dwButtonState): 120

When I rotate the mouse wheel backward I get:

> HIWORD(dwButtonState): 65416

I've spent way too much time looking for an answer as to why I'm not getting the expected results. If it's out there then I've missed it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `HIWORD` is I think a 16-bit value, and `65416` (which I also get) is `0xFF88` (negative if signed).

Comment: If actually running the code snippet yu might want to add these to lines to the bottom:  SetConsoleMode(hStdInput, fdwSaveOldMode);

 return 0;

Comment: @WeatherVane Makes sense, since 65416+120 == 65536! I wonder what is special about `+- 120` ? Seems like a random increment / decrement,

Comment: Yes, its `-120`.

Comment: A 16-bit value is promoted to `int` when passed for `%d`. Casting first as `(short)(HIWORD(ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState))` shows `-120`.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks. You are correct. The hiword value of a dword is 16 bit. Greater minds...

Comment: Why ±120? The bitfield flag settings are given in the page you linked.

Comment: @Weather Vane I don't know why the high/low values are what they are & I don't trust them to always be consistent. Microsoft's docs only stated that the number would always be positive for one case and negative for the other. Unfortunately their documentation doesn't go into a lot of detail.

Comment: In that case consider them arbitrary, as with C functions like `isupper` and `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 16-bit value is promoted to int when passed for %d. Casting first as (short)(HIWORD(ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState)) shows -120. –
Weather Vane